# Pagination Upper and Lower Limit

Tags: c#, linq, pagination

I'm trying to get the upper and lower limit for my pagination buttons.

I want there to always be 9 buttons. So initially with a current page index of 1 it would be:

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |

So my lower would be 1 and my upper would be 9.

When the current page index gets to 8 I would want the pagination to look like this:

| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |

Say the total pages where 15 and the current page index is now 14 the pagination would look like:

| 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 | 13 | 14 | 15 |

I cant seem to get it just right. My attempt using LINQ so far is (which is way off what I want it to do):

```
LowerCount = PageIndex;
HigherCount = (int)PageIndex + 5 < TotalPages ? PageIndex + 5 : TotalPages;
```

Comment: Could you provide more logic, because you could potentially use the `TakeWhile` or `SkipWhile` approach.  Also `Math.Min` and `Math.Max` approach.

Comment: What more do you want? I've made numerous attempts at this with LINQ and I cant figure it out.

Comment: Is this for a website? I've got a working model for Google-style pagination, modeled after this: http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2015/10/30/aspnet-mvc-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google. It's 10 buttons, not 9. I prefer having it in its own class so it can be unit tested. If you're interested I could stick it on GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With LINQ you can generate all pages with selected limits:

```
int totalPages = 15;
int range = 4;
int currentPage = 8;

Func<int> handleLimits = 
    () => Math.Min(Math.Max(1, totalPages - 2 * range), Math.Max(1, currentPage - range));

IList<int> pages = Enumerable
    .Range(handleLimits(), range * 2 + 1)
    .TakeWhile(p => p <= totalPages)
    .ToList();
```

Output:

```
| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
```

You can tweak parameters to see if they satisfy your requirements. Of course limits are `First()` and `Last()` elements.

Comment: I tried this but got -2.

Total Pages = 6 and Current Page = 0.

Comment: @Bad Dub Yup, the first part should be limited also, I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this fits my criteria perfectly and implementing it in my project. Thank you for your help. Also the inclusion of a Func was a nice touch.

Comment: @BadDub Glad you chose this solution, it's definitely the better implementation.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 cases.  The index is "close" to the beginning, the index is "close" to the end, or the index is in the middle.  Check those cases and determine the upper and lower values accordingly.

```
// This deterimines the maximum number of pages to show on each side of
// the current page.
int Range = 4
// If the index is close to the beginning
if(PageIndex <= Range + 1)
{
    LowerCount = 1;
    HighCount = Math.Min(2*Range + 1, TotalPages);
}
// If the index is close to the end but not the beginning
else if(TotalPages - PageIndex <= Range)
{
    LowerCount = TotalPages - (2*Range);
    HighCount = TotalPages;
}
// If the index is in the middle.
else
{
    LowerCount = CurrentIndex - Range;
    HighCount = CurrentIndex + Range;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could tackle in the following manner, excuse my assumptions though.  Since I don't know a great bit of detail.

```
var start = pages.FirstOrDefault(page => page >= (Math.Round(current - 4), 0);
var end = pages.FirstOrDefault(page => page >= (Math.Round(current + 4), 0);

var pagination = pages.SkipWhile(page => page != start).TakeWhile(page => page != end);
```

All you have to do would be to calculate your starting point and ending point and it'll collect the specific range.  You have some solid approaches though available.  Note, I may of screwed up less than or greater than, but the idea should be sound.

Comment: @Johnny I suck at reading, I'll revise to put that in there.  I like your answer btw.